# AttributeError: type object 'str' has no attribute

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv, attributeerror

First I created a pandas Dataframe called 'inventory' from a csv file

```py
instock = lambda x: True if inventory.quantity>0 else False
inventory['in_stock'] = inventory.quantity.apply(str.instock)
```

I tried to create a new column with boolean values, True for `quantity > 0` else False

When I try to print the updated dataframe I get the AttributeError

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, can someone help me to understand how the library is working in this case?
Shouldn't the variable instock be a boolean? It looks like it's treated like a generic object

Answer (score 2):

Lambda function here is not necessary, comapre column for greater like `0` for vectorized solution:

```
inventory['in_stock'] = inventory.quantity > 0
```

For learning purpose:

```
instock = lambda x: x>0 
inventory['in_stock'] = inventory.quantity.apply(instock)
```